# Error and warning when using dplyr with Google BigQuery connection

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery

I've established a successful connection to a Google BigQuery database in R using the following code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(bigrquery)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(bigrquery::bigquery(),
                  project = project,
                  dataset = dataset,
                  billing = billing)
```

But when I try to run a simply dplyr query such as:

```
tbl(con, "table_name") %>%
    summarise(total = n())
```

I receive the following error and warning:

```
Error: (L4:10): GROUP BY cannot refer to an empty field name
In addition: Warning message:
Translator is missing window variants of the following aggregate 
functions:
* %||%
```

I figured out if I add the argument use_legacy_sql = F to the dbConnect function, I can solve for the error but I still receive the warning

```
    total
    <int>
1 6259914
Warning message:
Translator is missing window variants of the following aggregate 
functions:
* %||%
```

I've never seen any information about needing to specify a legacy sql argument in the connection for dplyr to function, and the fact that I'm still getting a warning tells me something is still wrong with my connection. I've received the same warning when I establish a connection with the src_bigquery function in the bigrquery package.

Comment: Do you get the same error if you just try to submit the SQL directly instead of relying on dplyr?

Comment: dbGetQuery functions normally. I can run something like `dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE customer = 'B' LIMIT 10")` without any problem

Comment: I was looking at the [docs](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise.html) and it seems that, when using summarise, you have to specify a metric before or else do a group by before. I was trying to reproduce it but I get an error when calling tbl, which library versions are you using?

Comment: `other attached packages:
 [1] DBI_0.7         bigrquery_0.4.1 forcats_0.2.0   stringr_1.2.0   dplyr_0.7.4     purrr_0.2.4     readr_1.1.1     tidyr_0.7.2    
 [9] tibble_1.4.1    ggplot2_2.2.1   tidyverse_1.2.1`

Comment: Thanks, now I was able to use it but I get the same warnings. However, both the results and translated query (using `show_query()`) seem fine to me. So more than a connection issue to me it looks like something related to how the SQL queries are translated under the hood - [couple](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/blob/master/R/translate-sql-helpers.r) [links](http://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html).

Comment: I agree, It appears dplyr has issues translating SQL for BigQuery.